# Deploy Django rest framework application using docker and git on nginx AWS light sail

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, amazon-lightsail

I need to deploy Django rest framework application using docker and git on nginx AWS light sail. Can I get any general guideline please on how to start the process and what are the following steps? Or Any tutorials to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for advice;

There are 2 main options to choose from for deploying you dockerized django application to AWS Lightsail:

- A regular Lightsail VPS. I found [this tutorial](https://dev.to/koladev/deploy-a-django-app-on-aws-lightsail-docker-docker-compose-postgresql-nginx-github-actions-bo6) very helpful for setting up your dockerized django application on a regular Lightsail VPS.
- Lightsail Container Service. Furthermore, setting up your django docker application with Lightsail Container Service seems to be relatively straight forward if you [follow their instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/lightsail-containers-an-easy-way-to-run-your-containers-in-the-cloud/)

There are however a few points to take into consideration between choosing 1 of the 2 options:

- Setting up and getting your containers to run is easier on Lightsail Container Service, since you don't have to setup your VM to be able to run docker and it's toolings.
- The Lightsail Container Service itself also makes it easy to scale up to multiple nodes, instead of having to scale up your VM(s).
- The only big downside is that the Lightsail Container Service is way more expensive. You can read more as to why people think this is the case here:

  - [Reddit - Lightsail containers vs VPS](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/qc9ppu/lightsail_containers_vs_vps/)
  - [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1061333/why-does-running-a-containerized-app-with-aws-lightsail-cost-twice-as-much-as-us)

Good luck to anyone starting with lightsail docker and django:)